# Returning a Promise since async function by default return a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

```
 async add(model: IUser): Promise<User | null> {
        const { username, role, password, email } = model;
        const user = new User();
        user.username = username;
        user.role = role;
        user.password = password;
        user.email = email
        const userRepository = getRepository(User);
        try {
            const savedUser = await userRepository.save(user);
            return savedUser;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return Promise.reject(new APIError('User Already exists', Err.EmailAlreadyExists));
        }
```

Above code  used to save user data into mysql data base.It works perfectly fine.But what is the purpose of returning Promise since async function by default return a promise

Comment: yes, you can just `throw new APIError()` as it returns a Promise reject.

Comment: Do you mean the bit in the catch?,  Yes you could just throw an exception, but it's fine either way.

Comment: by the way `const savedUser = await userRepository.save(user); return savedUser;` - no point ... just `return userRepository.save(user);`

Answer (score 1):

> But what is the purpose of returning Promise since async function by default return a promise

There's no purpose. Actually,

```
return Promise.reject(new APIError('User Already exists', Err.EmailAlreadyExists));
```

is equivalent to

```
throw new APIError('User Already exists', Err.EmailAlreadyExists);
```